# How to add target="_blank" using replace operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to replace all the occurrences of

```
<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/{a random text}"></a>
```

So here I want to add target="_bank" to all the anchor tags which has the url 'http://localhost:4000/disease/description/*'.I put start because it indicates a random text.

I tried like this

```
var text = data.replace(/ href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/*/g,'href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/* target="_blank"');
```

But this doesnt work.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll()` to grab anchors starting with that url. From there, loop through them and set the `target` attribute via `setAttribute`:

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http://localhost:4000/disease/description"]');

Array.from(anchors).forEach(a => a.setAttribute('target', '_blank'));
```

```html
<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description">Disease Description 1</a>
<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description">Disease Description 2</a>
<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description">Disease Description 3</a>

<a href="">Dummy Link</a>
<a href="">Dummy Link</a>
<a href="">Dummy Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

I don't know why but this JsFiddle Code doesn't work here, but if you run it on your IDE, it works properly.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a');
a.href = 'https://google.com';
a.target = '_blank';
```

```html
<a>Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```js
var data='<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/{a random text}"></a>'

var c = data.replace('<a','<a target="_bank"')

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, in your case:

```js
data ='<a href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/{a random text}"></a>';
var text = data.replace(/href="http:\/\/localhost:4000\/disease\/description\/([^"]*)"/g,'href="http://localhost:4000/disease/description/$1" target="_blank"');
console.log( text );
```